# datatable in Rails using Foundation: Cannot call method 'fnInit' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datatables, zurb-foundation

Trying to use jquery datatables with a Rails 4.0.2 project using Foundation 4.

Per the install instructions on github, installed

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '1.12.2'
```

Added the required lines to my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require foundation
//= require select2
//= require jquery.Jcrop
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.foundation
```

...and application.css

```
*= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require select2
 *= require jquery-ui.min
 *= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom
 *= require jquery.Jcrop
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.foundation
```

Add this to my application.js file:

```
$(function(){
  ....
  $('.datatable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "foundation"
  });
});
```

In my html.erb file:

```
<table class="datatable">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Animal</th>
  <th>Species</th>
  <th>Breed</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <% @animals.each do |animal| %>
    <tr>
          <td><%= animal.name %></td>
      <td><%= animal.species %></td>
      <td><%= animal.breed %></td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

The table flashes briefly as un-formatted content and then disappears.  Inspecting the browser error in Chrome resources is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fnInit' of undefined."

Comment: It looks like foundation is never loaded. Be sure it is loaded and it is the latest version -> https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/integration/foundation/dataTables.foundation.js

Comment: Per dk's comment, I obtained the most recent dataTables.foundation.js via https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/integration/foundation/dataTables.foundation.js and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

delete this row from application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```